# How to get the sd from variable "b" of a day when the value of variable "a" is above a threshold

Tags: r, if-statement

If I have a hourly data set with 3 variables (time, a, b) and want to take a look at the standard deviation of "b" on specific days with outliers in "a", how can I do it? 
So the idea is: If a value of variable "a" is above a certain threshold e.g. 99 as in the following example, what is the standard deviation of variable "b" for the whole day. And what is the sd of "b" the day before and the day after.
I try to clarify the problem with an example:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame("time" =  seq( 
 from = as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 00:00", tz = "Europe/Berlin"), 
 to = as.POSIXct("2016-05-04 23:00", tz = "Europe/Berlin"),
 by = "hour"),  "a" = runif(96, min=0, max=100), "b" = runif(96, min=1200, 
 max=30000))
```

If this is the data, I would like to write a command like this:

```
test = data.frame("time" = df$time, "extreme" = ifelse(df$a> 99, sd(#take the sd of "b" for the day where df$a>99 occured) & sd(#and for the day before and after), 0 ))

test = subset(test, test$extreme>0) # to have a data frame with the important values only
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There is only case where you have a > 99, so the SD will be NA

Comment: Besides what @akrun said, if `extreme`is a sd then `subset(test, test$extreme > 0)` is almost always the same as `test`. (sd >= 0).

Comment: @akrun I want to calculate the SD for the 24 values of the variable "b" on the day where  a>99 occured. This cannot be an NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help @Dan Hall. I used some of your commands to find the right answer:

```
# Add additional variable with the daily sd of "b"
df_augmented = df  %>% group_by(date(time)) %>%
mutate(sd_price = sd(b)) 

#Filter the dates plus minus one day where the value is a>99
sd.extreme = data.frame("time" = df_augmented$time, 
                    "date" = date(df_augmented$time),
                    "sd_b_lagday" = ifelse(df_augmented$a>99, 
                                    Lag(df_augmented$sd_price, shift = 24) , 0),
                    "sd_b_day" = ifelse(df_augmented$a>99, 
                                 df_augmented$sd_price , 0),
                    "sd_b_leadday" = ifelse(df_augmented$a>99, 
                                     Lag(df_augmented$sd_price, shift = -24) , 0)
                    )

sd.extreme = subset(sd.extreme, sd.extreme$sd_b_day >0)

sd.extreme = sd.extreme[!duplicated(sd.extreme$date) ,]    

sd.extreme = sd.extreme[,-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the values on the day where `a` is above that threshold, and then compute the standard deviation of `b`for the day before, the day of, and the day after:

```
threshold_day <- day(df[df$a>99,]$time)
threshold_days <- c(threshold_day -1, threshold_day, threshold_day + 1)
outlier_days <- df[day(df$time) %in% threshold_days,]
outlier_days$sd_b <- sd(outlier_days$b)
head(outlier_days)
                 time        a        b     sd_b
# 1 2016-05-01 00:00:00 26.55087 14311.90 7730.978
# 2 2016-05-01 01:00:00 37.21239 13010.42 7730.978    
# 3 2016-05-01 02:00:00 57.28534 24553.06 7730.978
# 4 2016-05-01 03:00:00 90.82078 18622.08 7730.978
# 5 2016-05-01 04:00:00 20.16819 20056.05 7730.978
# 6 2016-05-01 05:00:00 89.83897 11372.08 7730.978
```

Note that this only includes the day, and the day after (since there is no data for the day before, and that a column with the standard deviation is not usually very helpful (since it's one value), but I think that's what you wanted...  please clarify if it's something else.

If you want the standard deviations alone, and you want them grouped by day, just split by the day, and apply sd. Again, you're only going to get two days (two groups), because you're threshold value was on the first day when you had data. So you can't include the day before (because there's no data from April).

```
tapply(outlier_days$b, day(outlier_days$time), sd)
```

And if you actually want it grouped, but want it in the data frame.. you can ram it back in, but you're probably better off using dplyr:

```
threshold_day <- day(filter(df, a>99)$time)
threshold_days <- c(threshold_day -1, threshold_day, threshold_day + 1)
filter(df, day(time) %in% threshold_days) %>%
    group_by(day(time)) %>%
    mutate(sd_b = sd(b))
```

Of course, if you send another reprex with different data, say one with dates in additional months, it will fail that without modifications that are appropriate for the expected input. That's why it's important to test for coverage across the expected inputs. For example, for data over more than a month, you'll want to group by the full date, rather than just the day. (swap date() for each day() and you'll get the result that works for that data).

Comment: That looks like what I meant. But where do you get day_df$b (third line) from?

Comment: it was a straggler... :) fixed now

Comment: Ok. This is pretty close. Thank you very much. This calculates the sd of the 3 days together. I would like to calculate the sd of the single days. In this case it would be:
`outlier_days$sd_b1 <- sd(outlier_days$b[1:24]) # for the day with a>99`
and
`outlier_days$sd_b2 <- sd(outlier_days$b[25:48]) # for the day after`

Comment: Is there a way to put it in one column?

Comment: Wait. Why did you correct it to `day_outliers$b`. This is only one value. I guess you wanted to change it to `outlier_days$b`

Comment: I have a problem with this answer. What if there is more than 1 day where a>99. Like:
`set.seed(1)
df = data.frame("time" =  seq( 
  from = as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 00:00", tz = "Europe/Berlin"), 
  to = as.POSIXct("2016-05-08 23:00", tz = "Europe/Berlin"),
  by = "hour"),  "a" = runif(192, min=0, max=100), "b" =  runif(192, min=1200, max=30000))

which(df$a>99)`

Then your code only gives me the right result for the first occurence.

Comment: Again, I had some trouble with your code. But I have found the solution now. See my Answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, you only have 1 case of `a > 99`. Therefore the result is `NA`. Nonetheless, this is the code that'd give you this value:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(a > 99) %>% mutate(sd_b = sd(b))
```

Result:

```
             time        a        b      sd_b
1 2016-05-01 17:00:00 99.19061 13626.44  NaN
```

Note that if you'd have a larger dataset that may contain `NAs` in `b`, you'd have to take this into account.

Comment: Misunderstood you, I get what you mean now. Pretty sure it's possible to do this with tidyverse, see http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise for extensive info on the packages. I am only learning it myself and I'm not sure how to deal with the date / hour yet.

Comment: Thank you. But I have already found the answer in another way. See my Answer.